# Can I somehow remap the left arrow and right arrow keys to the move functionality in Total Commander

Tags: total-commander

Can I somehow remap the left arrow and right arrow keys to the following functionality?

Left arrow -- move the cursor to the first item among the visible files and directories in the current tab
Right arrow -- move the cursor to the last item among the visible files and directories in the current tab

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you switch to "Brief" layout (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) the left and right arrow keys will have the functionality you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add into **[Configuration]** section of your **WINCMD.INI** file the following parameter:

```
SpecialCursorMovement=1
```

You can use the menu "***Configuration*** -- ***Change Settings Files Directly***" in the Total Commander itself for opening **WINCMD.INI**.